# Does the body parts of Devi Sati get cremated?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shakti, sati-goddess

I have heard somewhere that, after Devi Sati's dead body (after her self immolation in her own yogAgni) was cut into several pieces by Sri Vishnu's chakra, they fall in various places on earth. For Shakti to get re-united with Shiva, it was necessary for her to re-incarnate as Parvati. For this purpose, Shiva had cremated each of her body part separately (today's shakti peethas) and dissolved it's ashes in the river Ganga.

Does this version have a scriptural source (i am looking for a source that says Shiva 'Cremated' the various body parts of Sati's body).

Comment: "Does this version have a scriptural source " - Never heard this story. Also, Vishnu did not use his chakra. According to devi bhagavatam, he used his bow.

Comment: I have heard of this story but not cremated part.

Comment: @moonstar, I have heard of Chakra not bow. But don't go on my words, I am saying what I have heard from my mother. I haven't read that sculpture myself yet.

Comment: Shiva didn't cremate them. In Shaktipeetas, it is said those organs of Sati still exist.